# cannot drag and drop outlook msg to browser file upload

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-outlook, browser, microsoft-outlook-2010, google-drive

I am usually able to drag and drop an outlook msg to a file upload as a .msg file, however when i try to do so from a particular sender, the browser tries to open up the msg as a file on the browser instead, here is a giphy showing what happens;

https://giphy.com/gifs/uzPOSetxff738b0FBN

This same issue occurs for any file upload on a browser (like google drive or whatsapp file upload)

I have talked to microsoft chat support with no solution, as well as google drive support and they have no solution as well, as well as my mail service provider to no avail

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The file isn't a MSG file yet. Have you saved the email to a folder outside Outlook and THEN dragged it to the upload service?

Comment: Agree with @music2myear, I think it may be related to the message/file.  As I know, we could also drag the message when you compose a new message for testing, normally, it would add a .msg attachment in new message automatically .

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a .msg file yet, dragging it immediately from the Outlook message list to a web page running in a browser.

You can drag from Outlook to Word or other Office programs because they communicate using special protocols allowing them to understand the special characteristics of the data, but no such special protocols exist, nor could they due to security considerations when dealing with internet resources.

You need to drag the email to a folder, anywhere on the file system, then you can drag it into the site running in your browser if it supports it.

Comment: thanks for this response! what i'm confused about is why some messages/emails can do this while others can't? is there some security setting perhaps that forces this?